# page for each row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new to php and i've been struggling for several hours with making a unique page for all the articles. whatever i do it wont work.

i know i should convert the mysql to mysqli, but to begin with i just wanna make this work.

when i go to url/video.php?id=3 it just show a blank page it do not print "name" from the article table out

any suggestions?

video.php

```
<?php 

include "connect.php"; 


$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM `article` WHERE `id` = '.$id.'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Echo page content
echo $row['name'];
?>
```

im linking from index.php with following

```
 <a href="/video.php?id=<? echo $row[id]; ?>
```

which works.

Comment: Does the id in fact exist? Use [mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error) to make sure your queries are working fine

Comment: Dont know if it is the answer to your question but when i write echo $_GET['id']; it prints the id which in this case is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing that I see, but I assume that if you did:

- Have you managed to connect to the MySQL server?
- Did you select the
  database to use?
- you know the function [mysql_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) in PHP? And
- you know [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) in MySQL?

Try:

**MySQL:**

```
/**
* Connect and define your connection var
*/
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
/**
*   Select your database
*/
mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$connection);

/**
* Check if exists "id" in $_GET
*/
if( array_key_exists( "id" , $_GET ) )
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET [ "id" ],$connection );
    /**
    *   Remember use LIMIT
    */
    $source = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `article` WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1",$connection);
    
    /**
    * if you need print only name
    */
    if( mysql_num_rows( $source ) )
    {
        // print only name
        echo mysql_result( $source );
    }
    /**
    * but if you need retrive array
    */
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $source );
    echo $row["name"];
}
```

**MySQLi:**

```
/**
* Connect and define your connection var
*/
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
/**
* Check if is connected[ https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php ]
*/
if( mysqli_connect_errno() == 0 )
{
    /**
    *   Select your database
    */
    mysqli_select_db( $connection , "mydatabase" );
    
    /**
    * Check if exists "id" in $_GET
    */
    if( array_key_exists( "id" , $_GET ) )
    {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET [ "id" ]);
        /**
        *   Remember use LIMIT
        */
        $source = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `name` FROM `article` WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1");
        
        /**
        * if you need print only name
        */
        if( mysqli_num_rows( $source ) )
        {
            // print only name
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $source );
            echo $row[0];
        }
        /**
        * but if you need retrive array
        */
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $source );
        echo $row["name"];
    }

}
```

And, read bout the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) on MySQL

Good luck!

Comment: It prints the name out and following error:

Warning: mysql_result() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in / on line 29

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your quotations marks...

```
"SELECT `name` FROM `article` WHERE `id` = '.$id.'";
```

should be...

```
"SELECT `name` FROM `article` WHERE `id` = $id";
```

or

```
'SELECT `name` FROM `article` WHERE `id` = '.$id;
```

this doesn't do anything to stop sql injection...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested what values are in your $row variable? Use `var_dump($row)` to see the values.

BTW, you should check the ID:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  echo $id;
}
```

Comment: using that it do not show anything but if just use echo $_GET['id'];

then it print out the id which in this case is 3

Answer (score -1):

If id is a numeric field, as your question seems to imply, that should be

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM `article` WHERE `id` = $id";
```

if the id is a numeric field.

Note I also removed the dots inside your query string, which would make the query invalid whether `id` is a numeric field or not.

Comment: Rather a comment then an answer I think

Comment: The question was why it didn't work. My guess is that the id field is numeric and in that case querying it like a string won't work. Even if it would, the dots make the query invalid.

Comment: "guess" probably gives it away - answers shouldn't be guessed. Using `mysql_real_escape_string` should work with numeric values - I'm not saying however that you should use it over `intval` or something better fitting

Comment: Unfortunately I am not at Frederik's computer so I can't be sure, can I? But if you want to argue over words, let's pretend I said "inference (from the limited data as given)" instead. Anyway, my note that the dots inside the query make it invalid still stands; therefore I would appreciate your removing the downvote.